# Qual a diferença entre um método Sync e Async em Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de upload de arquivos em Node.JS. Tem um trecho no código que faz a transferência do arquivo para uma pasta específica no servidor...

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const formidable = require('formidable');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {

    const path = require('path');
    const oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
    const newpath = path.join(__dirname, '..', files.filetoupload.name);

    fs.renameSync(oldpath, newpath);
    res.send('File uploaded and moved!');
  });
});
```

Qual a diferença entre utilizar a função fs.renameSync() e fs.rename()? Realizando pesquisa no Google eu vi que posso utilizar a função fs.copyFile() que tem o mesmo resultado. Então... estou em dúvida, qual a melhor forma de utilizar?

Segue o código da parte do upload:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const formidable = require('formidable');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm()

    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        const path = require('path');
        const oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
        const newpath = path.join(__dirname, '..', files.filetoupload.name);
        fs.copyFile(oldpath, newpath, (err) => {
             if (err) return console.log(err);
             res.send('File Uploaded and Moved!')
     });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a função assíncrona não espera tarefa finalizar para começar a próxima o que deixa o código mais rápido
a função síncrona é mais simples de fazer porem o código sempre aguarda uma tarefa finalizar para fazer outra e isso diminui a velocidade de resposta
em programas pequenos é tranquilo mas quando o numero de requisições ao mesmo tempo aumenta a diferença de potencial é grande

```
      console.time("Assincrono");
       var counter = 0;

      for(var i = 0; i<1000; i++){
        fs.readFile("meu_arquivo.txt", (err, data)=>{
          if(err){
            return console.error(err);
          }
          counter++;
          console.log("Assincrono" + data.toString());
          if(counter === 1000){
              console.timeEnd("Assincrono");
          }
          });
           }
```

velocidade da execução //700 ms assincrona

```
 console.time("sincrono");
 var counter = 0;

 for(var i = 0; i<1000; i++){
  var data = fs.readFileSync("meu_arquivo.txt");
  console.log("sincrono" + data.toString());
 }
 console.timeEnd("sincrono");
```

velocidade da execução  //900 ms sincrona